# disable Ubuntu 10.04 spell check

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, spell-check

I have always disliked spell checking (may have something to do with being confronted with the condescending grammar checks in Word years ago) and I always try to get rid of the irritating red underlines wherever I see them.

Recently I started testing ubuntu lucid lynx (10.04) as a desktop environment, and the red lines are bloody everywhere. No matter how much I google it, I can only find references for enabling spell checking in different applications.

How do I completely disable spell checking in gnome? Am I the only one who doesn't want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a per-app setting.  No way around that, except *maybe* to uninstall aspell and ispell (but it could very likely break things):

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends aspell ispell
```

For Firefox: Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> "Check my spelling as I type"

For OOo: Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids -> Options: Check spelling as you type

Those are probably the two big ones.

Comment: Doing anything with `dpkg --force-depends` is generally not a good idea, and apt will require you to resolve dependencies before any actions anyway.

Comment: I said it'd likely break things...  Fair warning ;-)